# How fields are storing in list in Portia crawl?

Tags: python, scrapyd, portia, scrapinghub

**EDIT:** 
I am seeing that while running Portia spider the extracted fields are storing in a python variable list[] and returning the values while logging the extracted details in scrapyd.

I just want to know that how the fields are being extracted and storing those fields in list[] in spider run? (i.e. the work flow)

Comment: Hi @Prabakar, Can you please add more details. I am not able to understand it

Comment: I have edited my question.